# Apple's AVCamera Night Mode

Tags: ios, arrays, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture

I've been building a camera app using the AVFoundation and wanted to add NightMode support to it.
Apple features a stunning implementation for this, more about it can be read here: https://www.macrumors.com/guide/night-mode/

Now, the only "properties" I can find about "night mode" would be *low-light boost*, which only seems to be an iPhone 5 feature 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624602-islowlightboostenabled
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52574

I'd like to take advantage of the apple native night mode and implement it into my camera app. Is there any way to do so? Is this a feature that might be added to the SDK within the next releases? Did I miss something in the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, some time ago I tried to replicate what Apple calls NightMode.
Of course, there is any reference inside AVFoundation as occurs with HDR or SmartHDR.

The point is, what does NighMode do? How Apple archive this "effect"? 
Answering this questions points out why there is anything inside AVFoundation.

They basically blend multiple exposures replicating what in Photography is called "Long Exposure". The only way to do so would be to extract frame per frame from didOutputSampleBuffer and than find a (good) way to blend.
Of course there is a lot more involved, since each frame of the buffer is already pre-worked by isp.